# Error Data binding on dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, string-formatting

I Have Dropdwon on my aspx page :

```
    <td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextFormatString = "{0} - {1}" DataTextField = "value1,value2" DataValueField="Value2" class="ctrDropDown" onBlur="this.className='ctrDropDown';" onMouseDown="this.className='ctrDropDownClick';" onChange="this.className='ctrDropDown';">
     </asp:DropDownList>
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXXX_DevConnectionString_ddl %>" 
                                        SelectCommand="SELECT ParamId, ParamType, Value1, Value2, Value3, Status FROM Parameter WHERE (ParamType = 'BankId')">
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
</td>
```

I Want to make the data text field displayin value1 - value2 , i do `DataTextFormatString = "{0} - {1}" DataTextField = "value1,value2"` but it give me an error :

```
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'value1,value2'.
```

is it my code wrong ? or is there something i missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is fairly easy: perform the calculation in your SQL (into a new column name) and then use the new column name as your DataTextField.

For example, add a new Result field:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT ParamId, ParamType, Value1, Value2, Value3, Status, Value1 - Value2 As Result FROM Parameter WHERE (ParamType = 'BankId')">
```

and then reference this in DataTextField:

```
DataTextField = "result"
```